# Padding won't go away

Tags: html, css, html-lists, padding

I'm building this grid of links out of an unordered list and for some reason the container div has some padding on the left side that I can't seem to make go away. My goal is to have the unordered list centered in the container div with no extra padding on either side. Here is the code I have:

```css
.channels-container {
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
}
.channels-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 4;
}
.channels-container a {} .channels-container li {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="channels-container">
  <ul>
    <a href="/category/funny">
      <li>Funny</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/gaming">
      <li>Gaming</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/gifs">
      <li>GIFs</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/movies">
      <li>Movies</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/music">
      <li>Music</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/news">
      <li>News</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/pics">
      <li>Pics</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/politics">
      <li>Politics</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/random">
      <li>Random</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/science">
      <li>Science</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/sports">
      <li>Sports</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/style">
      <li>Style</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category=/technology">
      <li>Technology</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/videos">
      <li>Videos</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding is not in the div, its in your list.

```css
.channels-container {
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
}
.channels-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 4;
  padding:0em;
}
.channels-container a {} .channels-container li {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="channels-container">
  <ul>
    <a href="/category/funny">
      <li>Funny</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/gaming">
      <li>Gaming</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/gifs">
      <li>GIFs</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/movies">
      <li>Movies</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/music">
      <li>Music</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/news">
      <li>News</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/pics">
      <li>Pics</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/politics">
      <li>Politics</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/random">
      <li>Random</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/science">
      <li>Science</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/sports">
      <li>Sports</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/style">
      <li>Style</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category=/technology">
      <li>Technology</li>
    </a>
    <a href="/category/videos">
      <li>Videos</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Browser has default styles. You need to override those styles. Add following style

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/Eq80pPix4OZg8cnSjq2g?p=preview

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't change anything. Does this mean there is some CSS somewhere else in my code that is altering it?